# auditd / auditctl: Are chown and chmod “write” -w type of an operation?

Tags: chmod, chown, linux-audit

Are chown and chmod “write” -w type of an operation?

I'm using auditd to watch folder permissions. There are different options read, write, execute, attributes.

I just want to watch chmod or chown changes on the directory.

Is chown/chmod a write type of operation on the system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those operations are `a`(=attribute change)

Comment: Thank you ! . . .